# Do campaign stages have hidden collectibles?

Tags: splatoon-3

In Splatoon 1 every campaign level had a hidden Sunken Scroll. In Splatoon 2 every level hid a Sunken Scroll and Sardinium. In Splatoon 3 I've only encountered collectibles in the stage select hubs. The only "collectibles" I've found in the stages are power eggs.

Do campaign stages in Splatoon 3 have hidden collectibles like the previous games?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Splatoon 3 single player campaign you can collect many hidden collectibles, but all of them (after checking a couple of collectibles walkthrough on Youtube) seem to be located only in the main hub sites, as you have already noticed.

---

Here's a list of Splatoon 3 collectibles:

- Sardinium

[image]

- Gold records

[image]

- Food tickets

[image]

- Card packs

[image]

- Sea Scrolls

[image]

Comment: I'm specifically asking if collectibles can be found in the campaign levels, not the stage select hubs. I've edited the question to clarify.

Comment: @Stevoisiak my bad! Anyway you seem correct, I can't find any in-level guide for collectibles, so I'm confident to say there are none.

Comment: 100%ed the solo game and can confirm: There are no collectibles in the levels. All of them are in the hub.